# Yii2 - Show form fields based on dropDownList

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii2, onchange

**I have the following dropDownList**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'moradaalternativa')
    ->dropDownList(
        [
        'Não' => 'Não',
        'Sim' => 'Sim'],
        ['prompt'=>'Faça a sua escolha'],
    );
?>
```

**What i'm trying to do is:**
If the value is = Sim, then some other form fields that are hidden by a css class show up below the dropDownList, and if the value is = Não, then the form fields hide from the page again.

I know that there is a 'onchange' property like javascript but i don't know how to apply it to this effect or even if i need to use it.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: can you share your  success code? thanks before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple, all you need is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document.body).on('change', '#your-id', function () {
        var val = $('#your-id').val();
        if(val > 0 ) {
          $('.class').hide();
        } else {
          $('.class').show();
        }
    });
});
```

And just change the names as needed. For Yii2 you can wrap it, then you can just put the code in a view file but it's better to put it in a JS file:

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS

code here

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Comment: Yes. But how can i attribute a ID to dropDownList field of the ActiveForm class. THe dropDownList belongs to Yii2 and not to ordinary HTML select element?

Comment: It will be the same ID everytime, use Firebug to see what the ID is then just use that and it will always be the same.

Comment: Well, it kinda works... The issue is that Sim or Não values all show the hidden form field, and if the form is showing when i select the value Não it does not hide again :(

Comment: Just wrap the fields you want to hide in a container div and use that id, and set the initial show property with css (display:none) Also you might need to change the > o to be explicit about what you want. Just test it and use console.log to see what values you're getting etc

Comment: That's right. I made it. It's working now. Just needed to change the condition for something like val == 'Nao'... Many thanks... I will accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks! Happy to have helped :)